# LocationProvider

Tags: asp.net, security, sitemap

We need to replace the menu system in our main ASP.NET application. So naturally we're looking at the ASP.NET `SiteMapProvider` and `Menu` controls. However we also need enough security to prevent users from directly entering URLs that they shouldn't have access to. We can do this by putting `<location>` entries in **web.config** and securing them individually but that's going to be a PITA to manage across multiple web servers.

Is there a `Provider` that can be used to, well, provide the equivalent of the `<location>` entries? I haven't been able to find one, and it's slightly frustrating given the existence of the [ConfigurationLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationlocation.aspx) class.

Alternatively is there a configuration option we're missing in SiteMapProvider that will restrict users from getting to URLs they shouldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create rights & profiles to manage wich pages a user can see?
I usually create a user class which implements the IPrincipal security interface. On every request to your application, you check the rights of a particular user and output the SiteMap's nodes allowed for this user.